# Find The $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{5^{7n}}{3^{{(n+1)}^2}}$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

I am trying to use the Squeeze theorem.
is is a valid claim? or is it better left and right hand sides expression to select?

$$0\leq\dfrac{5^{7n}}{3^{{(n+1)}^2}}\leq\dfrac{5^{7n}}{3^{n^2}}$$
$0$ because it is a fraction with both nominator and denominator positive.

$\dfrac{5^{7n}}{3^{n^2}}$ because $(n+1)^2\geq n^2$ so the denominator is smaller and the expression is bigger and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{5^{7n}}{3^{n^2}} \rightarrow0$
so $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{5^{7n}}{3^{{(n+1)}^2}}\rightarrow 0$

Comment: Looks solid enough.

Comment: There is a typo in your question $(n+1)^2\geq n^2$

Comment: @Hugo thanks fixed

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is correct. The only thing that needs justification is $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{5^{7n}}{3^{n^2}}=0$. But this is readily seen from $\frac{5^{7n}}{3^{n^2}}=\left(\frac{5^7}{3^n}\right)^n$.

Comment: way it this $\frac{5^{7n}}{3^{n^2}}=\frac{5^7}{3^n}$ right? can

Comment: Exponents don't cancel that way.  You can, on the other hand, say $5^{7n}/3^{n^2}=(5^7/3^n)^n\le5^7/3^n$ for $n$ "large."

Comment: @gbox, $5^7\cdot5^n=5^{7+n}$, not $5^{7n}$, and likewise for $3^n\cdot3^n=3^{n+n}=3^{2n}$, not $3^{n^2}$.

Comment: $(\frac{5^7}{3^n})^n$ so $\frac{5^7}{3^n}\rightarrow 0$ and so does $(\frac{5^7}{3^n})^n$ ?

Comment: Sorry for my oversight. Thanks for correcting it.

Comment: As for your question @gbox, $5^7$ is a fixed number so for say $n>20$ we have $5^7 < 3^n$ so $\frac{5^7}{3^n}<1$. Recall that $x^n\to 0$ for $|x|<1$.